# existence of a line on a cubic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to understand the proof in Miles Reid's book: Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry, that: "there exists at least one line l on S", where S is a non-singular cubic surface. In the book the proof is broken down in to three parts. I would be very grateful to anyone who could give a detailed explanation of what's happening in each of these parts. Here's a link to the book: http://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/abenito/varios/ReidAlgebraicGeometry.pdf

Comment: I would suggest that you ask something more specific. For example, what is the first bit that you do not understand? And how have you tried to understand it?

Comment: Ok. Firstly, why in step 1 can we write $f$ as $$f=X^{2}Z_{0}-Y_{O}^{3}+gT$$ where $g=g_{2}(X,Y_{0},Z_{0},T)$ is a quadratic form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in the comments, Reid reduces the problem to studying the intersection $C = S\cap T_PS$, which is a singular plane cubic. Since he wants to prove that $S$ contains a line, he assumes $C$ is nondegenerate (i.e., not ii or iii of Proposition 7.1). Thus $C$ is a cusp or a node. He works with the cusp case, claiming the node case to be similar. By a projective change of coordinates, he assumes that the tangent space $T_PS$ is defined by $T=0$ and the cusp is defined by $X^2Z - Y^3 = 0$. Since $C = S\cap T_PS = (f=0)\cap (T=0)$, we know that $X^2Z-Y^3$ is $f(X,Y,Z,0)$. Thus, $f(X,Y,Z,T) = X^2Z-Y^3 + Tg(X,Y,Z,T)$, that is, when we set $T=0$ we must get the equation of the cusp, but there could be another homogeneous term divisible by $T$. Since $f$ is cubic, $g$ must have degree $2$.